# Moving reusable workflow to a different Site Collection

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have done a resuable workflow in my test environment. I want to move it to every site collection in the farm.

I want do it with powershell, because we have many site collection. 
I'm using `Add-SPUserSolution` and `Install-SPUserSolution` as shown below.

```
$wspName="abc.wsp"
$wspPath="C:\wsp\"+$wspname
$WebAppsUrlColl =  "http://myspsite"

foreach($WebAppUrl in $WebAppsUrlColl)
{
    Write-host "Scanning Web Application:"$WebApp.Name

    $WebApp=Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppUrl

    $SitesColl = $WebApp.Sites

    foreach ($Site in $SitesColl)
    {
              Write-host "Scanning Site Collection:"$Site.
              Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath $wspPath -Site $Site -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
              Install-SPUserSolution -Identity $wspName -Site $Site -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
    }
 }
```

After I run the code, it works. But feature is not activated:

[image: not activated]

When I go to **Site Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Solutions**, I can see my wsp file.

Also when I go to **Site Settings > Site Actions > Manage site features** , I can see my WorkFlow Template. But the workflow template is deactivated.

When I run `Get-SPFeature -Site http://myspsite` I can not WorkFlow Template

How I can activate Workflow Template Feature with powershell?

Comment: `Get-SPFeature -Web http://myspsite | %{ Enable-SPFeature -Identity $_ -URL http://myspsite}` See this [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ff607803.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That code gives error for every feature "Enable-SPFeature : Feature 'featureName' (ID: 00bfea71-..) is already activated at scope "http://myspsite"

Comment: I haven't see the foreach before, sorry..... Try inside the `foreach`: `Get-SPFeature -Site $Site `